# PHP / MySQL is slow, can't figure out why?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, query-performance

The first function `recentlyModified()` runs in 1 second exactly, even though it's polling for two shows. I admit, it has a lot less parameters to work with but that's darn fast at approximately 0.5seconds per show.

The second function `myList()` however runs in 16 seconds approximately for 4 titles, 11 seconds for 2, and 6 seconds for one. This is on average of course.

```
<?php

include_once './php/loadanime.php';

function crunchyrollNews() {
    echo('<iframe class="rss fullwidth fullheight" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/crunchyroll/animenews?format=xml"></iframe>');
}

function recentlyModified($count) {
    $mtime = microtime();
   $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
   $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
   $starttime = $mtime;

    $animedb = new mysqli("localhost", "animedeck", "W8a7fs5gu");

    $query = $animedb->query("SELECT id, img, name, description  FROM animedeck.animelist ORDER BY modified DESC LIMIT " . $count . "");    

    if($query) {
        $result = $query->fetch_all();

        echo '<div class="recentanimemodule">';

        echo '<h1 class="h1 borderb">AnimeDeck Recent</h1>';

            foreach($result as $id) {
                echo '<div class="recentanimepiece">';
                echo '<img class="recentanimeposter" src="';
                echo $id[1];
                echo '" />';    
                echo '<a class="recentanimeurl" href="'; //a href start
                echo './viewanime.php?id=' . $id[0]; 
                echo '">';
                echo '<div class="recentanimename">';
                echo $id[2];
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</a>'; //a href end
                echo '<div class="recentanimedes">';
                echo $id[3];
                echo '</div>';  
                echo '</div>';
            }

        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo "Failed to retrieve entries.";
    }

       $mtime = microtime();
   $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
   $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
   $endtime = $mtime;
   $totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
   echo "This module was created in ".$totaltime." seconds"; 
}

function myList($status, $sort, $startindex, $count) {

    $mtime = microtime();
   $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
   $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
   $starttime = $mtime;

    $animedb = new mysqli("localhost", "animedeck", "W8a7fs5gu");
    $orderby;
    $title = "Recent";
    $rstatus = ", status='" . $status . "'";

    if($status == "all") {
        $rstatus = null;
    }

    if($startindex == null) {
        $startindex = 0;    
    }

    switch ($sort) {
    case "recent":
        $sort = "DESC";
        $orderby="modified";
        $title = "Recent";
        break;
    case "oldest":
        $sort = "ASC";
        $orderby="modified";
        $title = "Oldest";
        break;
    case "az":
        $sort = "ASC";
        $orderby="animename";
        $title = "A to Z";
        break;
    case "za":
        $sort = "DESC";
        $orderby="animename";
        $title = "Z to A";
        break;
    }

    $query = $animedb->query("SELECT animeid FROM animedeck.mylist WHERE userid='" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "' " . $rstatus . " ORDER BY " . $orderby . " " . $sort . " LIMIT " . $startindex . ", " . $count . ""); 

    if($query) {
        $result = $query->fetch_all();


        echo '<div class="myanimemodule">';

        echo '<h1 class="h1 borderb">MyList ' . $title . '</h1>';

            foreach($result as $id) {
                $info = loadSemiAnime($id[0]);

                echo '<div class="animeid">' . $id[0] . '</div>';
                echo '<div class="myanimepiece">';
                echo '<img class="myanimeposter" src="';
                echo $info['img'];
                echo '" />';    
                echo '<a class="myanimeurl" href="'; //a href start
                echo './viewanime.php?id=' . $id[0]; 
                echo '">';
                echo '<div class="myanimename">';
                echo $info['name'];
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</a>'; //a href end
                echo '<div class="myanimedes">';
                echo $info['description'];
                echo '</div>';  
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="animelistoptions">';
                echo '<span onClick="setStatus(' . $id[0] . ', \'';
                echo loadAnime($id[0], "name") . "'";
                echo ', 0)" id="stowatch' . $id[0] . '" class="bluebutton">To Watch</span>';
                echo '<span onClick="setStatus(' . $id[0] . ', \'';
                echo loadAnime($id[0], "name") . "'";
                echo ', 1)" id="swatching' . $id[0] . '" class="bluebutton">Watching</span>';
                echo '<span onClick="setStatus(' . $id[0] . ', \'';
                echo loadAnime($id[0], "name") . "'";
                echo ', 2)" id="swatched' . $id[0] . '" class="bluebutton">Seen</span>';
                echo '<span onClick="setStatus(' . $id[0] . ', \'';
                echo loadAnime($id[0], "name") . "'";
                echo ', 3)" id="srewatching' . $id[0] . '" class="bluebutton">Re-Watching <i class="fa fa-heart"></i></span>';
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<script>getStatus(' . $id[0] . ');</script>';
            }

        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo "Failed to retrieve entries. Error: " . $animedb->errno . " --- " . $animedb->error;
    }


       $mtime = microtime();
   $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
   $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
   $endtime = $mtime;
   $totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
   echo "This module was created in ".$totaltime." seconds"; 

}

?>
```

So my problem is that I'm not sure what in my code is causing it to take so long? 6 seconds for just one iteration? Is it the PHP? I thought MySQL executes pretty quickly so I'm thinking it's the PHP. But which part?

I'm not familiar on what is a good and bad practice for PHP so I don't know what's really slowing my functions down.

Here are my loadAnime() and loadSemiAnime() functions:

```
<?php 

function loadAnime($id, $toload) {

    $animedb = new mysqli("localhost", "animedeck", "W8a7fs5gu");
    $load = $animedb->query("SELECT " . $toload . " FROM animedeck.animelist WHERE id=" . $id . "");

    if($load) {
        $result = $load->fetch_assoc();

        echo $result[$toload];
    }   
}

function loadSemiAnime($id) {
    $animedb = new mysqli("localhost", "animedeck", "W8a7fs5gu");
    $load = $animedb->query("SELECT img, name, description FROM animedeck.animelist WHERE id=" . $id . "");

    if($load) {
        $result = $load->fetch_assoc();
        return $result;
    }       
}

?>
```

Comment: Try "EXPLAIN SELECT animeid FROM animedeck.mylist WHERE userid=..." and post its result

Comment: What do the loadAnime() and loadSemiAnime() functions do.

Comment: Holy... thank you so much Kickstart. I had known that running an entire query everytime I needed one variable was bad so I made the loadSemiAnime class to load the three variables I needed one time and then just reuse the variables. However I forgot to remove those down there.
I am now officially down to 4 seconds which is 1second/per show. THIS IS GREAT. But now I think I can do even better with general performance. Currently my database is performing well so I guess the real next step is to try and optimize the code then the database?

Comment: Added in the hastebin for my load functions.

Comment: Those functions (not sure if you are still using them) connect to the database every time they are executed. This is another overhead as well as executing the query every time they are executed.

Comment: The query is different every time as it is pulling a different title every time. However in my logic, maybe I could bypass this at a later time.
For now, I must ask, would it be better to just open up the database connection for the duration of the function and close it at the end instead of re-opening it time and time again? If I open it from within the function, can other functions from other files (e.g. the loadanime.php file that has the functions you see) see it?

Comment: Best to just open once and pass it through. Or you could set it up as a class, do the connect once in the constructor of the class and then just do the query. Could also be possible to store details when returned so if the same details are requested you can just return them without the doing the query. However probably easier with this routine to just do a JOIN in the main query and avoid the need for the functions at all.

Comment: Do any of the values you use in these queries come from the user e.g. in `$_GET` or other superglobals? If so you are likely at risk of SQL injection - use parameterisation to fix this. This is supported my mysqli.

Comment: (Aside: please do not use pasteboards for code - they frequently are deleted remotely, which then forces us to close the question. We would rather keep questions so that future readers may learn from them! Thanks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is dynamically built so difficult to see anything there, but building it looks simple so I suspect the query is quite simple.

However you have functions that connect to the database and do a query for every record returned by the main query. These seem unnecessary as it looks like you can just do a JOIN to get the fields in the main query:-

```
SELECT a.animeid, b.img, b.name, b.description
FROM animedeck.mylist a
LEFT OUTER JOIN animedeck.animelist b
ON a.animeid = b.id
WHERE a.userid='" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "' " . $rstatus . " ORDER BY " . $orderby . " " . $sort . " LIMIT " . $startindex . ", " . $count . "
```

Comment: So if I implement that, it should more or less work? What does LEFT OUTER JOIN do in summary?

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN is to join the 2 tables together, but where the table on the right doesn't need to have a matching row (in which case the columns from that table will have values of NULL).

Comment: Thank you so much. This brought down my execution time to 1 second even though I'm pulling 4 titles. I'm going to have to use this Join thing from now on! It's amazing! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem as well.

```
$query = $animedb->query("SELECT animeid FROM animedeck.mylist WHERE userid='" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "' " . $rstatus . " ORDER BY " . $orderby . " " . $sort . " LIMIT " . $startindex . ", " . $count . "");
```

Your "userid" is in your where clause, on a big table this is going to be super slow if this field is not index.  Go into your MySQL table and add an index to this column eg.

```
ALTER TABLE `animedeck` ADD INDEX `userid` (`userid`)
```

This should speed things up considerably.

General rule of thumb, any field that is in a where clause needs an index. MySql by default will index primary keys. So you don't need to manually index an primary keys (i.e. the ID field).

Answer (score -1):

Well, I ended up implementing all the changes to the DB settings as advised here:https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/

Comment: My database was installed alongside Plesk so I don't know if that optimized it already or not. I'm running Windows Server 2012.